# ¿Cómo obtener el progreso del curso en Moodle 4?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, postgresql, moodle

dejare abajo mi consulta. Mi problematica es que quiero obtener el progreso que se ve como cuando entras a la interfaz del sistema y el usuario ve si tiene un 50/100% del avance del curso, ese es el progreso que estoy buscando conseguir y agregar en mi consulta.

Tengo moodle 4.0, les dejo mi consulta a ver si me pueden dar alguna idea.

```
SELECT u.id as user_id,
       u.firstname,
       u.lastname,
       c.id         as course_id,
       c.fullname   as corusename,
       act.id       as activity_id,
       act.itemname as activity,
       grades.finalgrade as activity_grade


FROM mdl_course AS c
/*CONEXION DE CURSO A USUARIO*/
         INNER JOIN mdl_context AS ctx ON c.id = ctx.instanceid
         INNER JOIN mdl_role_assignments AS ra ON ra.contextid = ctx.id
         INNER JOIN mdl_user AS u ON u.id = ra.userid
/*FIN CONEXION DE CURSO A USUARIO*/
/*CONEXION USUARIO A ACTIVIDADES*/
 INNER JOIN mdl_grade_items act ON act.courseid = c.id AND act.itemmodule = 'scorm'
/*FIN CONEXION USUARIO A ACTIVIDADES*/
/*CONEXION ACTIVIDADES Y CALIFICACIONES*/
INNER JOIN mdl_grade_grades grades ON grades.itemid = act.id and grades.userid = u.id
/*FIN ACTIVIDADES Y CALIFICACIONES*/

WHERE c.id in (21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26)  

ORDER BY act.courseid
```